# Get Location From Center of Screen Swift MapKit

Tags: swift, location, mapkit, screen, center

I'm new on Swift Programming, and I'm trying to build an app that I can get the coordinates of the center of the view with MapKit and Swift 2.

I already can get the current location, but I need if I move on the map, the location set to the new point which will be the center of the screen.

Can you help me with this please?.

Regards,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the regionDidChangeAnimated delegate method and call mapView.centerCoordinate. It will look like the following:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        var center = mapView.centerCoordinate
   }
```

Also make sure that your Class is extending `MKMapViewDelegate` and you are calling 
`self.mapView.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: great.. thanks a lot, this give me a few ideas that how can I solve my problem, but seems like it doesn't work, I mean, I put the code you give me, and I scroll the view and nothing happends

Comment: `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        let center = mapView.centerCoordinate
        print(center.latitude)
        print(center.longitude)
    }`

Comment: Are you extending MKMapViewDelegate? If not make sure you add the delegate in your class declaration and then call self.mapView.delegate = self in your viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Just updated the answer with this additional information. Valeu Felipe ;)