# Resize a MKCircle with a Slider SWIFT4

Tags: swift, mapkit

My purpose is to do quite the same thing as in the Facebook app.
Here is my current code :

```
class MapFilterViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var applyButton: UIButton!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        applyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.delegate = self

    }

    func showCircle(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance, mapView: MKMapView) {
        let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: radius)
        mapView.add(circle)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

        let center =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center : center, span : span)

        print("longitude = \(location.coordinate.longitude), latitude = \(location.coordinate.latitude)")


        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        showCircle(coordinate: location.coordinate, radius: 1000, mapView: mapView)
        print(location.coordinate)

    }
    @IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: Any) {
        distanceLabel.text = String(distanceSlider.value) + " km"


    }
```

I don't get how I'm supposed to take the radius of the circle in my sliderValueChange action and get the same animation

Already searched a lot, most of the results are in Objective-C and I'm learning Swift for 3 weeks now.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do that is to remove the circle and create a new one (because you cannot modify the radius of the cercle).

Here is a bit of code you could use:

```
var circle: MKCircle?

@IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
    mapView.remove(circle)
    let newRadius = sender.value * 1000
    circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: radius)
    mapView.add(circle)
}
```

As you are learning I think you should start with something like that. You could also try to play with the scale of the overlay but I think it will be a bit more complicated and I'm not sure the result will be much better.

Comment: I'm trying to make it your way, thing is that I can't access coordinate since it is in the locationManager func.
And I don't think it will do the trick when I will try to make the circle "move" (like in facebook app)

Comment: Save the coordinates as a property like the circle and use 'didSet' on the location to update the circle when the location changes.

Comment: OK, how can I retrieve the location of the " camera " (where the user moved it)

Comment: This is an other question. And you'll find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378118/get-center-coordinates-form-mapkit-swift-2-and-display-in-uilabel

Comment: If you think I answered your question do not forget to validate my answer. If you really want to learn swift you will have to learn how to read objective-c because a lot of the answers for iOS are in objective-c. But don't worry it's quite similar to swift. Good luck.

Comment: Don't worry, that was my intention.
One last problem is that the mapView.remove(circle) doesn't work (in your first answer)

Comment: does your code is somewhere online like in github so I can look at it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm forced to unwrap circle! calling remove function since my circle is initialized as MKCircle?
Here is the code after your feedbacks (sorry don't know how to put "class" in the code area, I'm new to stackvoerflow):

class MapFilterViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var distanceSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var applyButton: UIButton!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var circle : MKCircle?
var coords : CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    applyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    distanceLabel.text = String(Int(distanceSlider.value)) + " km"

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    mapView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.delegate = self

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

    let center =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center : center, span : span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    circle = MKCircle(center : location.coordinate, radius: CLLocationDistance(distanceSlider.value*100))
    mapView.add(circle!)

    coords = location.coordinate

}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapView.remove(circle!)
    circle = MKCircle(center : mapView.centerCoordinate, radius: CLLocationDistance(distanceSlider.value*100))

    mapView.add(circle!)
}

@IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: Any) {
    mapView.remove(circle!)
    distanceLabel.text = String(Int(distanceSlider.value)) + " km"
    let newRadius = distanceSlider.value*100
    circle = MKCircle(center : coords!, radius: CLLocationDistance(distanceSlider.value*100))

    mapView.add(circle!)
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    // If you want to include other shapes, then this check is needed. If you only want circles, then remove it.
    let circleOverlay = overlay as? MKCircle
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: circleOverlay!)
    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor(named :"darkRed")
    circleRenderer.alpha = 0.1

    return circleRenderer
}
```

}

Comment: Nevermind, got it fixed by initializing my circle somewhere else than in my locationManager :)