# How to make a draggable map with a centered annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am attempting to make a draggable annotation. But instead of making the annotation dragable, I want the mapView to move around the annotation. So the annotation will stay in the center of the mapView the entire time, but when the user gets done dragging the map around and clicks save, then I can get the annotation coordinates. 
What is a way that I can do this? 
Assume I already have an annotation on the screen.

My ViewDidLoad

```
    mapView.delegate = self

    let anno = MKPointAnnotation()
    anno.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.417110, longitude: -92.914788)

    mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
```

My view for annotation

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }
    let identifier = "marker"
    var view: MKAnnotationView
    if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequeuedView
    } else {
        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.isDraggable = true
        view.canShowCallout = false
    }
    return view
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705790/get-location-from-center-of-screen-swift-mapkit

Answer (score 0):

Add an image of a marker on top of the map, add it as a subview. Then you can get the center coordinates usually using mapView.centerCoordinate when the user stops scrolling.

```
let markerImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Orange"))
markerImageView.center = mapView.center
mapView.addSubview(markerImageView)
```